# Remoting exception: Object 'xxx.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I am developing web chat integrated to site on ASP.NET (.NET 4.5) using SignalR(v1.1.0). Also chat connected to Jabber server using WCF-service. Sometimes I receive the next exception in external code:

Remoting exception:

> Object 'xxx.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the
>   server.

Full Stacktrace:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233077
  Message=Object '/76fe3e3d_b7ca_4973_9cf3_9d84e6d4268a/9emtey6i64mqzcxou+wc1_5x_808.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.
  Source=WebDev.WebHost40
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection.get_Connected()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.IsClientConnected()
       at System.Web.HttpResponse.get_IsClientConnected()
       at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_IsClientConnected()
       at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CheckIsClientConnected(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireQueuedTimerCompletion(Object state)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:
```

I noted that it happens when client try to connect to SignalR hub.

I did'not find useful information about it in SO and other resorces.
I don't know what is it and how it should be fixed. Could you explain it, please. Any information will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit your question and show code that illustrates the problem. Include the *full exception trace* and tell us which line throws the exception. It is impossible to answer your question without more information.

Comment: The problem appears to be that the service you're trying to connect to doesn't exist or has been disconnected (exactly what the error message says). Have you created a service named `xxx.rem`? Is your application asking for `xxx.rem` when it should be called `MyChatService` or something else? I suspect that either your service isn't running or your client is configured incorrectly and asking for the wrong service.

Comment: @JimMischel, No, I have not so service. I found the similar problem here:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/208
Now I know that problem relate with SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using cassini (WebDev server), upgrade to IIS express and be happy

Comment: Not sure why this answer is downvoted.  I tried it on my current situation and it works for me.